# How to implement Amazon Kinesis Streaming to process data in real time in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I have gone through the doc of Amazon web Services (AWS) for Kinesis Streaming (real time data processing). But I am getting confuse about how to implement Kinesis Streaming.

- Installed SDK for iOS in project.
- Written code of Cognito Credentials with region and pool-ID.
- Successfully done with AWSServiceConfiguration.
- In viewcontroller, I have written a code to save data in
  AWSKinesisRecorder Stream.

But how can I know about data is Successfully saving in Stream? How can I put a print log?

I want to show Successfully saved data in console.

```
AppDelegate Code:


 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        AWSLogger.default().logLevel = .verbose
        
        let CognitoPoolID = "ap-northeast-1:430840dc-4df5-469f"
        let Region = AWSRegionType.APNortheast1
        let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:Region,identityPoolId:CognitoPoolID)
        
        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:Region, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
        AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
        
        return true
    }
```

ViewController code:

```
import UIKit 
import AWSKinesis

class ViewController: UIViewController {

       var kinesisRecorder : AWSKinesisRecorder! = nil

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
    
        //use AWSKinesisRecorder with Amazon Kinesis. The following snippet returns a shared instance of the Amazon Kinesis service client
         kinesisRecorder = AWSKinesisRecorder.default()
    
    
          configureAWSKinesisRecorder()
        saveDataInStream()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    /*
     * Method to configure perties of AWSKinesisRecorder
     */
    func configureAWSKinesisRecorder()  {
        //The diskAgeLimit property sets the expiration for cached requests. When a request exceeds the limit, it's discarded. The default is no age limit.

        kinesisRecorder.diskAgeLimit = TimeInterval(30 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 30 days
    
    
        //The diskByteLimit property holds the limit of the disk cache size in bytes. If the storage limit is exceeded, older requests are discarded. The default value is 5 MB. Setting the value to 0 means that there's no practical limit.

        kinesisRecorder.diskByteLimit = UInt(10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10MB
    
    
        //The notficationByteThreshold property sets the point beyond which Kinesis issues a notification that the byte threshold has been reached. The default value is 0, meaning that by default Amazon Kinesis doesn't post the notification.

        kinesisRecorder.notificationByteThreshold = UInt(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
    
    }

    /*
     * Method to save real time data in AWS stream
     */
    func saveDataInStream()  {
   
    
        //Both saveRecord and submitAllRecords are asynchronous operations, so you should ensure that saveRecord is complete before you invoke submitAllRecords.
    
        // Create an array to store a batch of objects.
        var tasks = Array<AWSTask<AnyObject>>()
        for i in 0...5 {
            //create an NSData object .
            //StreamName should be a string corresponding to the name of your Kinesis stream.
            //save it locally in kinesisRecorder instances

            tasks.append(kinesisRecorder!.saveRecord(String(format: "TestString-%02d", i).data(using: .utf8), streamName: "my_stream")!)
        }
    
        ////submitAllRecords sends all locally saved requests to the Amazon Kinesis service.
        AWSTask(forCompletionOfAllTasks: tasks).continueOnSuccessWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> AWSTask<AnyObject>? in
            return self.kinesisRecorder?.submitAllRecords()
        }).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as? NSError {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        }
    
        )
    
    
    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AWSKinesis` directly instead of using the `AWSKinesisRecorder`.

The `putRecords` method (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSKinesis.html#//api/name/putRecords:completionHandler:) will write records to the stream for you explicitly, instead of abstracting record saves in a recorder.

This method gives you a `completionHandler` block you can use to see exactly what Kinesis is responding with, be it successful record ids, or error codes. From there you can log to your console or do whatever else you like with the response. The caveat is that you need to batch records manually for the call to `putRecords`. You could use user defaults or realm to store the events locally, and then flush them to Kinesis on a schedule. This is what the recorder gives you for free.

Alternatively, if you just want to see that events are going through your Kinesis stream successfully, you can hook up a Kinesis Firehose stream to your Kinesis stream, which you can configure to deliver your event data to S3, Amazon ElasticSearch, or Amazon Redshift: https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in Kinesis to do what you want it to do. However, an alternative is to query the service that the stream is putting the data in (S3, dynamo, etc...)

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell me how to save real time data in AWS for ios custom app?

Comment: You can use Kinesis to pipe the streams. But you need to save it somewhere like Dynamo, S3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is connect a consumer for that stream. Eg: KinesisFirehose. Then from that Firehose you could direct its output to an S3 bucket.